# Increment absolute value of int preserving sign?

Tags: binary, int

What's the shortest way to **inc** or **dec** the absolute value of an `int` **but keep the signs** (`+` `-`) ?

```
int a = 5;
int b = -7;
// increment abs of both
// a -> 6
// b -> -8
// incrementing 0 wasn't interesting me, I guess it can stay 0
```

*(I'm sure it's not that hard but I will probably end up with some lines of code. But I wonder if I can make that very short, 1-liner ?). I also removed C# tag because this might be interesting for all kinds of languages.*

Comment: What should happen for 0?

Comment: @mini-me - you have two very good answers - one preserves zero, the other increments it. Can you disambiguate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IF 0 should be left as 0: since `Math.Sign` returns +1, -1, or 0, you can do:

```
a += Math.Sign(a);
```

Comment: Boom. very very nice answer dude.

Comment: I like this, clean and simple.

Answer (score 4):

If you want 1 to be the answer if you feed it 0, here's a way:

```
a = Math.Sign(a) * (Math.Abs(a) + 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

i'd imagine an in-line comparison is cheaper than an abs call:

```
int res = a + (a >= 0 ? 1:-1)
```

this assumes 0 is a positive number.

Comment: Or if you just want to update the variable `a += a >= 0 ? 1 : -1;`

Answer (score 1):

Since the C# tag was removed from the question, I would like to offer this (C) answer:

```
#define absInc(a) ((a<0)?(--a):(++a))
```

once you place this in your header, you can do the following in your code (tested, works):

```
int a = -4;
absInc(a);
printf("a is now %d\n", a);
```

result:  `-5`

I re-posted this since my original (similar) answer got a lot of downvotes since this type of construct doesn't exist in C#. I had not paid attention to the tag...